# How to import 3d model (.obj) into Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, 3d-model

I have some models from `sketchup` and export it to .obj, and I want to use those models to be displayed in my apps. I've followed the instruction from google dev, but I still don't understand the part where are we should place the [ModelRenderable](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/import-assets).

Can you guys explain it to me about that step from google dev, or suggest another tutorial to import .obj files to my project apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can put result of converting to asset or raw folder, asset is more suitable because it have not limitation of naming conversion.

1. Create folder 'mymodel' on top level of you project
2. Copy you obj file into mymodel/models subfolder
3. Run Import Sceneform Asset with following parameter and click finish:
   Source Asset Path : mymodel/models/model.obj
   Material Path  : default
   .sfa Output Path : mymodel/models/model.sfa
   .sfb Output Path : src/main/assets/model.sfb
4. Add info into app's build.gradle:
   sceneform.asset(
   'mymodel/models/model.obj',
   import.'default',
   'mymodel/models/model.sfa',
   'src/main/assets/model')
5. Rebuild project
6. Init ModelRenderable builder with asset resource

   `ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(this, Uri.parse("model.sfb"))
               .build()
               .thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable = renderable)
               .exceptionally(
                   throwable -> {
                     Log.e(TAG, "Unable to load Renderable.", throwable);
                     return null;
               });`

Comment: Can you tell me what is init? And how to do init? Is that create new java file and named it as modelRenderable or something? And if so where should i create that?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk samples, loading hellosceneform project ant take a look in HelloSceneformActivity.java .